# Using FirebaseAnalytics in a cocoapod resulting in error during compilation

Tags: ios, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I am using FirebaseAnalytics in a cocoa development pod, and facing an error during compilation, saying

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FIRAnalytics", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in FirebaseService.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My pod file is like

```
  pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics', :inhibit_warnings => true
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', :inhibit_warnings => true
```

and the podsec in the pod is like

```
  spec.dependency 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
  spec.dependency 'Firebase/Analytics'
```

It so only happens when I use any `Analytics.*` in my code in the development pod. If I move the logic to the `AppDelegate` (the main app project), there is no error.

I have tried cleaning up the `Framework Search PATHs` from both app and the development pod, as suggested in https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7614#issuecomment-786827116, but still no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are using M1 Chip Mac ?

Comment: Mine is intel chip mac